# NAT setup on Proxmox

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I'm trying to set up NAT on Proxmox VE 7.3-4. I followed this guide but changed the IP range and didn't do any port forwarding yet https://bobcares.com/blog/setup-nat-on-proxmox/

I edited `/etc/network/interfaces` to add `vmbr1` and then ran `ifup vmbr1`. I can ping `10.10.0.1` from the host itself, so `vmbr1` is up, and i can also ping the host from the VM. However, i cannot access the internet from within the VM, or even ping `1.1.1.1`. Seems like a routing issue but i'm not sure what.

**Host `/etc/network/interfaces`:**

```
    auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

    iface eno3 inet manual

    iface eno4 inet manual

    auto vmbr0
    iface vmbr0 inet static
            address *.*.*.179/24
            gateway *.*.*.254
            bridge-ports eno3
            bridge-stp off
            bridge-fd 0
            hwaddress AC:1F:6B:63:77:4A

    auto vmbr1
    iface vmbr1 inet static
            address 10.10.0.1/22
            bridge-ports none
            bridge-stp off
            bridge-fd 0

            post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
            post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.0.0/22' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
            post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.0.0/22' -o vmbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Routing table and ping from VM:**

```
     % ip route
    default via 10.10.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
    10.10.0.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.10.0.100 
     % ping 10.10.0.1
    PING 10.10.0.1 (10.10.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from 10.10.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.086 ms
    64 bytes from 10.10.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms
    ^C
    --- 10.10.0.1 ping statistics ---
    2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.068/0.077/0.086/0.009 ms
     % ping 1.1.1.1
    PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
    ^C
    --- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
    3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2055ms
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Forgot to add the conntrack zone:

```
post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
```